# Passing a parameter in Action Link mvc razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to pass a value into the action link to call a controller method inside an Iframe this is my code:

controller:

```
    public ActionResult CallFastPay(string monateryAmount)
            {

//some code logic here
            }
```

view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FastPay";
    var url = ViewBag.url;
}
<h2>FastPay</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('#myButton').click(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("CallFastPay")'

            var amount = document.getElementById("monateryAmount").value

            $('#myFrame').attr(@Url.Action("CallFastPay", amount));
        });
    });
</script>
<br />
<iframe id="myFrame" width="600" height="500"></iframe>
<br />
<span>Amount</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="monateryAmount" name="monateryAmount" />
<br />
<button id="myButton" onclick="">Submit</button>
```

I am getting the error that amount does not exist in the current context. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you console.log amount what do you get? Is it undefined or does it have a value?

Comment: yes it has the value inserted inside the text box

Comment: You cannot mix razor code (your `@Url.Action()`) and javascript variables (`amount`) like that. One is executed on the serer and the other on the browser

Comment: is there any solution for this ? i have done alot of research but really found nothing

Comment: you can call method and pass parameter using ajax call

Comment: Use `url + '/' + amount`

Answer (score 0):

Change your script like this,

```
 $('#myButton').click(function () {
      //var url = '@Url.Action("CallFastPay")'
      var amount = $("#monateryAmount").val();
      $.ajax({
       url:"YourControllerName/CallFastPay/"+amount,
       //Or you can write like this, url: url + '/' + amount,
       type:"Get",
       success:function(data)
        {
         //Your success message here, for example
         alert("Amount submitted successfully!");
        }
       error:function(data)
        {
         //Your error message here
        }
      })
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem

Comment: What do I have to code in the success and error section ? sorry for the stupid question but I am quite new to ajax calls

Comment: May I know, are you returning any data or message from your action method ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I have added a alert message there. You can show anything and anywhere like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below: As your syntex is wrong.

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    var amount = $("#monateryAmount").val();
  $.ajax({
        url:'@Url.Action("CallFastPay","ControllerName")',
        data:{'monateryAmount':amount},
       type:Get,
       success:function()
        {
         //Your success message here
        }
       error:function()
        {
         //Your error message here
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the results in the iframe then you need to set the `src` attribute.

In your razor view you can set the base url using your action link, and setup the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("CallFastPay")'; 

    $('#myButton').click(function () {            

        var amount = $('#monateryAmount').val();
        var url = baseUrl + '/' + amount;

        $('#myFrame').attr('src', url);
    });
});
</script>
```